# How do I Reset page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game and I want the board to reset once one player has won.

As of now, when someone gets three in a row, the board disappears as per the `.remove` function I am using, but `game.newgame` is not being called and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var gameboard = {

    initialize: function() {
        for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
                unit.appendTo('#gameboard');
            }
        }
        console.log(100);
        gameboard.addId();
    },

    addId: function() {
        var id = 1
        $('.unit').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('id', id);
            id++;
        });
    }
};

var game = {

    newGame: gameboard.initialize(),

    currentPlayerTurn: players.firstPlayer.token,   

    displayToken: function() {
        $('.unit').click(function() {
            if(game.currentPlayerTurn === 'X' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("X");
                game.currentPlayerTurn = players.secondPlayer.token;
            } else if(game.currentPlayerTurn === 'O' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("O");
                game.currentPlayerTurn = players.firstPlayer.token;
            }
            game.win($(this));
            //console.log($(this));
        })
    },

    win: function(div) {

        game.winCombos.forEach(function(element) {
            element.forEach(function(unitIndex){ 
                if(unitIndex.toString() === div.attr('id').toString()) {
                    var elementIndex = game.winCombos.indexOf(element);
                    var unitIndex = element.indexOf(unitIndex);
                    game.winCombos[elementIndex][unitIndex] = game.currentPlayerTurn;       
                }

                var counter = 0

                for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                    if (element[i] === game.currentPlayerTurn) {
                    counter ++;
                } 

                if(counter === 3) {
                    game.gameOver(true);

                }


                }

            })
        })
    },

    gameOver: function(bool) {
        if (bool === undefined) {
            bool = false;
        }
        $('.unit').remove();
        $('.selected').remove();
        game.newGame;
    },

    winCombos: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Try replacing `game.newGame;` with `game.newGame();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `newGame` function should just be a reference to gameboard.initialize. There's no point in storing the extra reference.

Remove this line:

```
newGame: gameboard.initialize(),
```

And replace:

```
game.newGame;
```

with

```
gameboard.initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `newGame` property should be a function:

```
newGame: function() {
  gameboard.initialize();
},
```

Second, call `game.newGame();` instead of `game.newGame;`

In your original game object `newGame` property was just declared by returning value of `gameboard.initialize()` method.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

`newGame: gameboard.initialize(),`

to be one of the following:

`newGame: gameboard.initialize,`

or

`newGame: function () { gameboard.initialize(); },`

either assign it a function (rather than a function call) or assign it a function definition